# How to export the df result as a mysql table

Tags: mysql, text-formatting

I can get a table by following command

`df -h|column -t|sed -E 's/ +/\t/g'`

> [image]

I hope to make it be a mysql table.This is my current try

```
[root@localhost ~]# df -h|column -t|sed -E 's/ +/\t/g'>test
[root@localhost ~]# mysql -pmypassword mydatabase <test
```

But it cannot work.Is there any method can do this?

Comment: I think you can compare your problem with the question of  [how to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605765/importing-a-csv-into-mysql-via-command-line) import csv to [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16011143/insert-csv-to-mysql-using-ubuntu-terminal-via-shell-script)

Comment: @Hölderlin Thanks, just those Chinese cannot show normally..

Comment: @yode you can add `LANG=C` (without semicolons or any other symbols) in front of `df` to convert it to English.

Comment: @rush Thanks a lot.That very useful to me.

Comment: @rush And I mean the Chinese character show normally in my ssh terminel by it is not normal when I export into mysql..